# NullPointerException at OnClickListener in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, onclicklistener

```
package com.example.geoquiz;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

public class QuizActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button mTrueButton;
    Button mFalseButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    mTrueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.correct_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        mFalseButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.incorrect_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.quiz, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Please help guys. Getting a NullPointerException at mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener().
I know other ways to set the OnClickListener but just wanted to know what's wrong with this code. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please be sure to set useful tags - I have added the android tag as without it nobody who can answer the question is likely to see it.

Comment: Sorry forgot. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your `mTrueButton`. Likely with a call to `findViewById()` after `setContentView()`, like you're initializing `mFalseButton`.

Comment: Oops Sorry. It was there in the code. Probably forgot to add it here. I initialized the buttons, still the same error persists.

Comment: ... and make sure your `activity_quiz` layout actually contains view with the ids you're trying to find with.

Comment: The buttons are present in the xml layout, any other way to assure that the ids are present in the activity_quiz?

Comment: If it's so, clean and rebuild the project in case resource ids are out of sync between binary XML and generated R.java.

Comment: I just cleaned the project. I don't know how to rebuild a project. Can you please help me with it?

Comment: I've just created a new project and wrote the whole code again. I'm getting the same error at the same place. Please help.

Comment: Recheck you have the view in the layout and are calling `findViewById()` after `setContentView()`.

Comment: The "view" in the sense the "Button" right? Yes it is present in the layout file. And findViewById() is called after setContentView(). Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Finally solved the problem. I wrote the layout code in the fragment.xml instead of the activity.xml. That was very dumb.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize `mTrueButton` buttons:

```
mTrueButton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `mTrueButton` like you did with `mFalseButton`

For eg.

```
mTrueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); \\ button1 is whatever id you have given to mTrueButton
```

Until you do that `mTrueButton` is null and trying to call any method on it will result in a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize your mTrueButton like this:

```
mTrueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

before setting onClickListener

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to initialize the buttons:

```
Button mTrueButton;
Button mFalseButton;
```

just add the `findViewById()` method to each button so you can access to them.

```
mTrueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```